# How to eliminate variable given conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality

$P$ and $S$ are the common cause of $c$. If $P(C=true| P,S )$ is given as the table below, and $P(S=true) =0.3$, $P(P=true) =0.9$ how can I eliminate $S$ and calculate $P(C=true | P=true )$ and $P(C= false| P=true)$ ? Many thanks for your help.

$P(C=true | P,S)$:

```
+p  +s +c  0.05
+p  -s +c  0.02
-p  +s +c  0.03
-p  -s +c  0.001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum out a variable using the law of total probability. So 
$$
P(c=true | p=true) = P(c=true | p=true, s=true) * P(p=true, s=true) + P(c=true | p=true, s=false) * P(p=true, s=false)
$$
This can intuitively be understood as summing probabilities across mutually exclusive spaces. [This Stanford pdf](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1178/lectureHandouts/040-cond-probability.pdf) explains where the equation comes from well.

Because p and s are independent

$$
P(p=true, s=true) = P(p=true) * P(s=true)
$$
$$
P(p=true, s=false) = P(p=true) * P(s=false)
$$
So do the substitution in the above equation and you're good to go.

Comment: I know I can sum out P(C, P,S) , can I sum out P(C | P, S) as well? How to calculate P(C=false | P=true) then? I am confused as if I use P(C,P,S) = P(P,S)*P(C|P,S) , and sum out  P(C, P,S), the results are different from suming up  P(C, P,S) directly. Which one is correct? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, read your question too quickly and assumed your table was the joint distribution. Have updated the answer

Comment: Thanks. could you explain a bit more why the first equation ?

Comment: should the last bit be P(s= false, p= true)?

Comment: I mean should it be +(=|=,=)∗(=,=true) ?

Comment: You're right. Updated the answer to fix that and gave a brief explanation with a link for a deeper understanding